# Marlin Bed-Leveling Vs Skew Correction

Tags: marlin, bed-leveling, z-probe

I've added a G29 command in my starting script to do bed leveling process before every print. It works fine and compensates my bed during prints. But when I print larger models, they're all skewed in both XZ and YZ plane. So I decided to use Marlin's Skew Correction option.

I printed [Calibration Squares](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2563185) and entered measurements for XZ and YZ plane. I left XY corrections as default (Because I have no problem in this plane).
Unfortunately it sounds like Bed-Leveling and Skew-Correction don't get along! Many different problems happen!!!

- I get "Probing failed" error.
- Z-axis doesn't move (moves for compensating but not for new layer)
- Bed-Leveling process fails sometimes.
- bed center (X=0,Y=0) gets shifted...

Is there a bug in Marlin? Or I have to find another way to correct my XZ and YZ skew-ness ?!?

Comment: It's probably best to notify the developers and open a bug report to report your findings. Do note that a print, made on an unlevelled bed, levels out in the first 10 layers or after about one cm. A cube printed on an uneven bed is therefore never perfectly square.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be answered by the developers after a bug report has been submitted. Otherwise it would be speculation on the implementation and the solution.

Comment: OK, I haven't got any response to my report...  close it. It's Allright.

Comment: You can always reopen it and answer it once you have gotten a response. Note that closing a question is not bad, it prevents the system to pop-up the question once in a while. Re-opening will be possible by community re-open or moderator intervention. Thanks for your understanding!

Comment: Could you add a link in your question to the bug report that you filed?